# Setting shape types in groups with different overlay plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, shapes, group

I am hoping to fine tune ggplot2 shape types in two overlay plots when coding by groups.  Is this possible?  I created a strip plot with points for mean observations, coded with two different shapes for two different factors of seeding rate, and three different colors for different fertilizer price scenarios.  I included jitter observations of the values used to calculate these means, also coded by the same color and shape groups listed for the mean points.  I included lines showing standard errors for each mean.
To improve visualization, I would like the jitter observations to be open shapes and the means to be closed shapes.

```
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot()+  geom_jitter(data=econ4,position=position_jitter(0.2),aes(x=location,y=profit,shape=seeding.rate,colour=urea.cost.USD,alpha=0.05))+theme_bw()+geom_hline(yintercept=0)+labs(y = "profit per ha (USD)")
p<-p+geom_point(data=econ4,aes(x=location,y=mean.profit,colour=urea.cost.USD,shape=seeding.rate))
p<-p+geom_linerange(data=econ4,aes(x=location,y=mean.profit,ymin=mean.profit-se.profit,ymax=mean.profit+se.profit,colour=urea.cost.USD)) 
#p<-p+scale_shape_manual(values=1:2)
p<-p+scale_colour_manual(values=c("#0072B2","#009E73", "#CC79A7"))
p<-p + coord_flip()
p<-p+scale_shape_manual(values=1:2) #this changes all shapes to open.  I would like this to apply only to the geom_jitter.
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sure could this be achieved. But to help you any further we need [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data to run your code and to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want different shapes for jittered and mean points mapping `seeding.rate` on `shape` isn't sufficient. Instead you have to "recode" `seeding.rate` to differntiate between jittered and mean points and to get four different shapes. To this end you could map e.g. `paste0(seeding.rate, ".jitter")` on the `shape` aes in `geom_jitter` and `paste0(seeding.rate, ".mean")` on the `shape` aes in `geom_point`. As a result we have four different categories to which we could assign your desired four different shapes.

Additionally I slightly refactored your code and instead of computing the `mean` and `se` manually I use `stat="summary"` to compute the statistics on the fly.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

econ4 <- data.frame(
  location = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE),
  urea.cost.USD = sample(c("300", "550", "1000"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  seeding.rate = sample(c("Mirsky", "Poffenbarger"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  profit = rlnorm(100, 4) - 100
)

ggplot(econ4, aes(profit, location, colour = urea.cost.USD)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_jitter(
    position = position_jitter(0.2),
    aes(shape = paste0(seeding.rate, ".jitter")), alpha = .8,
    size = 2
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = paste0(seeding.rate, ".mean")),
    stat = "summary", fun = mean, size = 2
  ) +
  geom_linerange(stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_se") +
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#CC79A7")
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = c(Mirsky.jitter = 16, Mirsky.mean = 21, Poffenbarger.jitter = 17, Poffenbarger.mean = 24),
    breaks = c("Mirsky.jitter", "Poffenbarger.jitter"),
    labels = c("Minsky", "Poffenbarger")
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "profit per ha (USD)", shape = "seeding rate")
```

[image]

Comment: I am now noticing that the `geom_linerange(stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_se")` only creates standard error lines for each of the three urea cost scenarios.  I am hoping to create se lines for each of the combinations or seeding rate and urea cost.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure could this be achieved. For example you could map `seeding.rate` on an aesthetic for the linerange too e.g. `geom_linerange(aes(linetype = seeding.rate), stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_se")`. Or use the group aes, e.g. `aes(group = paste(seeding.rate, urea.cost.USD, sep = "_"))` .

Comment: Thank you.  This worked well for me `geom_linerange(aes(group = paste(seeding.rate, urea.cost.USD, sep = "_")), stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_se")`